# NiFi ListS3 Processor includes parent file path as a flow file

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi

My files in s3

**s3://my_bucket/my_path/data/category/myfile.txt**

Using the ListS3 processor with the bucket and pass "my_path/data/category/" as the prefix
I will get TWO flow files:

**"s3://my_bucket/my_path/data/category/myfile.txt"**
and
**"s3://my_bucket/my_path/data/category/"**

The 2nd one here is not an actual flow file but only a path to it.

*How can I change my processor configuration to only get the entry for "myfile.txt"?*

Also, FetchS3 seems to be picking this up and sending it to the next processor "ExecuteScript" which is modifying the contents of the file.

This **ExecuteScript** processor is obviously failing but not logging it, instead, it's just stuck in the queue.

*How do I make it send this to the failure path instead of being stuck in the queue?*

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! There is a '**Delimiter**' property in the ListS3 bucket where I needed to include '/' as a delimiter. This is used to exclude the parent directory by Amason S3.

Comment: can you please share the configuration details, i tried adding the ‘/‘ in the delimiter but it did not work can you please show me the prefix and delimiter configuration?